# Matlab R2016a bug - unable to interact with figure when waiting for user input

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, freeze

In Matlab R2016a while waiting for a user input or paused I'm **unable to interact with figure controls**, like zoom. This doesn't happen in older Matlab versions.

This only happens when a figure was created before and also CLOSED. Run the code below using  `createFig1 = 0;` (no bug) and `createFig1 = 1;` (bug).

Bug will NOT happen if:

- Fig1 is not created
- Fig1 is created but not closed
- Pause is removed

Similar problem also reported [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/301306-how-to-interact-with-figure-while-input-is-active) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/273942-plot-controls-don-t-work-in-version-2016a-when-waiting-on-user-input-from-input-command?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).

Sample code:

```
clearvars; close all;

% If fig1 is created here AND closed, zoom control in fig2 becames unresponsible !
createFig1 = 1;
if createFig1
    fig1=figure;
    title('Press any key or click to continue...');
    disp('Press any key or click to continue...');
    k = waitforbuttonpress;
    close(fig1); clear fig1;
end

%fig2=figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
fig2=figure;
plot(randn(1000,1));
title('Fig A');

% #### Bug here if fig1 was created and closed !!!! ####
% #### zoom control gets unresponsible !! ####
disp('Zoom in/out and press any key to select points...')
pause;
```

Comment: I can recreate your bug. However, when running your example with `createFig1 = 0`, I can only do 5-10 interactions with the figure before the figure window hangs. Reading the comments on the links you provide, I get the impression that `pause` now pauses the GUI by design, and being able to do 5-10 interactions is the buggy behavior...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a workaround, there is none.

This is a bug in MATLAB R2016a, and has been fixed in MATLAB R2016b.

Unfortunately, if this is a critical issue for you, I recommend either downgrading or upgrading your MATLAB, and it should be fine.

Comment: This is sad, can you point out references for your affirmations?

Comment: Yep, I actually work at MathWorks, and this has been a known bug. It was fixed in R2016b.